# C# interface static method call with generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, static

Is there a simple way to implement this, and if possible without instanciating an object :

```
interface I
{
     static  string GetClassName();
}

public class Helper
{

    static void PrintClassName<T>() where T : I
    {
         Console.WriteLine(T.GetClassName());
    }
}
```

Comment: How would an implementation of your interface look like?

Comment: Given that the interfaces define instance members, how do you expect to call an interface member without an instance? if you want the class name, use typeof(T) and dump the interface.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  Sure `typeof(T).FullName` would do the job?

Comment: GetClassName was just for the sake of the exemple...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try an extension method instead:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
     string GetClassName();
}

public static class IMyInterfaceExtensions
{
    public static void PrintClassName<T>( this T input ) 
        where T : IMyInterface
    {
         Console.WriteLine(input.GetClassName());
    }
}
```

This allows you to add static extension/utility method, but you still need an instance of your IMyInterface implementation.

You can't have interfaces for static methods because it wouldn't make sense, they're utility methods without an instance and hence they don't really have a type.

Comment: Ok, but do you think we can avoid the input parameter. Say we have a kind of singleton pattern for the interface or in any other way?

Comment: Note sure what you mean - you'd call this extension methods as if it was an instance one: new MyImplementation().PrintClassName()

Comment: You can't avoid the instance, unless you switch to using reflection (like @Kent Boogaart's answer), but then you shouldn't really use generics as you're just passing the type

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer -- a brilliant way to add "util" methods targeted at specific interfaces.  I would also recommend the MSDN documentation on extension methods (link below).  Note that MSDN example appropriately namespaces the extension methods so that calling bodies must specifically include the extensions.  Extension Methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can not inherit static methods. Your code wouldn't compile in any way, because a interface can't have static methods because of this.

As quoted from [littleguru](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/250972-Static-Inheritance/?CommentID=274217):

> Inheritance in .NET works only on
>   instance base. Static methods are
>   defined on the type level not on the
>   instance level. That is why overriding
>   doesn't work with static
>   methods/properties/events...
>
> Static methods are only held once in
>   memory. There is no virtual table etc.
>   that is created for them.
>
> If you invoke an instance method in
>   .NET, you always give it the current
>   instance. This is hidden by the .NET
>   runtime, but it happens. Each instance
>   method has as first argument a pointer
>   (reference) to the object that the
>   method is run on. This doesn't happen
>   with static methods (as they are
>   defined on type level). **How should
>   the compiler decide to select the
>   method to invoke?**

Comment: For sure the compiler can't choose (or if he can that because we explicitly call the right static focntion with the right class). However can we do no have something around this with genereic ?

Comment: Probably it could be possible. But this design is chosen to keep it more simple and clean.

Comment: Just to clarify, C# does indeed allow static members to be declared on interfaces that then need to be provided by implementors. An example of such an interface in the BCL itself is ```IParsable<T>```, it defines a static ```Parse``` and ```TryParse``` method.

Comment: It's important to note that that wasn't the case back then. So the emphasis should be on "now".

Answer (score 3):

I also tried to setup a static method on an interface a little while ago, not sure why now. I did bookmark this so maybe it helps:

[Interface with a static method by using extension methods](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2009/06/interfaces-with-static-methods-reducing.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're just after the type name, you can just do this:

```
public class Helper
{
    static void PrintClassName<T>()
    {
         Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1) but I'd add that you shouldn't really do this - if all you're doing is passing a type you should use a regular parameter instead: PrintClassName( Type input ) { Console.WriteLine(input.Name); }

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a `static` `property`, `event` or `method` on an interface definition is not considered a legal definition. This is because interfaces are considered contracts and as such, represent something that *will* be implemented by every client instance of that interface.

A `static` declaration essentially states that the `static` member does not require a physical client implementation in order to execute the required functionality and this falls short of the general concept of interfaces: providing a proven contract.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a qualified "not really but Sort Of". You can provide a static extension method to all implementors of a given interface and can then call this from your implementer in a property or another method. As an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace InterfacesWithGenerics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Helper.PrintClassName<Example>(new Example());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Example : I
    {
        #region I Members

        public string ClassName
        {
            get { return this.GetClassName(); }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public interface I
    {
        string ClassName { get; }
    }

    public class Helper
    {

        public static void PrintClassName<T>(T input) where T : I
        {           
            Console.WriteLine( input.GetClassName()) ;
        }
    }

    public static class IExtensions
    {
        public static string GetClassName(this I yourInterface)
        {
            return yourInterface.GetType().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have an interface (I) which defines the property we care about and a static extension method (GetClassName) which is applied to all members of its type which does the grunt work of getting the information we want. We Have a Class (Example) which implements the I interface so when we call our static helper class passing in an instance of Example, it runs the static method against it. Unfortunately it is not valid to reference the type T directly within the method itself as a variable, you'll have to pass an instance into the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the className as attribute on the specific class. This is the preferred ay to store metadata in .net. This way you can query the attribute for the given class and you do not need an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - sort-of - if you don't mind defining new types that proxy instance calls to static methods:

While an `interface` can only declare **instance** members, you can use a couple of simple tricks with C#'s generics, without needing reflection, to accomplish what you're after (and without resorting to Java-style `AbstractFactoryBeanFactory` design-pattern overuse).

What we can do, is define a separate `struct` (i.e. a value-type) that contains instance members that call-into the static members we want.

So if we have this interface:

```
interface IStaticFunctionality
{
    void DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance();
}
```

...and we want to do something like this:

```
void AGenericMethodThatDoesntHaveAnInstanceOfT<T>()
{
    T.DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance();
}
```

...then we can do this:

```
void AGenericMethodThatDoesntHaveAnInstanceOfT<T>()
    where T : struct, IStaticFunctionality
{
    T t = default;
    t.DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance();

    // Note the above code uses `T t default;` instead of `T t = new T()`.
    // This is because the C# compiler currently replaces `new T()` with `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` in the generated bytecode.
    // This has poor performance compared to `default(T)` or a normal non-generic constructor call, but the compiler does this because it's a workaround for a design-bug back in C# 6.0: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-new-constraint-in-c-a-perfect-example-of-a-leaky-abstraction/ 
}
```

So if we have different types with the `static void DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance` method, we just need to define `struct` implementations of `IStaticFunctionality` for each of those types:

```
class Foo
{
    public static void DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo");
    }

    struct Static : IStaticFunctionality
    {
        void DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance() => Foo.DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance();
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public static void DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bar");
    }

    struct Static : IStaticFunctionality
    {
        void DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance() => Bar.DoSomethingWithoutAnObjectInstance();
    }
}
```

So then a call-site for `AGenericMethodThatDoesntHaveAnInstanceOfT<Foo>` would actually look like:

```
AGenericMethodThatDoesntHaveAnInstanceOfT<Foo.Static>();
```