# Implementing Interface with static methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr, il

Suppose I have the following ILAsm code:

```
    .class public interface abstract ITest
    {
        .field public static int32 counter

        .method public static void StaticMethod(string str)
        {
            ldarg.0
            call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
            ret
        }

        .method public virtual abstract void InstMethod(string) { }
    }
```

Is it possible to define a class in C# that implements this `ITest` interface?

I can implement this interface in ILAsm:

```
    .class public TestImpl extends [mscorlib]System.Object implements ITest
    {
        .method public virtual void InstMethod(string str)
        {
            ldarg.1
            call void ITest::StaticMethod(string)
            ret
        }

        .method public specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor()
        {
            ldarg.0
            call instance void .base::.ctor()
            ret
        }
    }
```

and successfully use implemented class in C# code:

```
        var testImpl = new TestImpl();
        testImpl.InstMethod("I'm static!");
```

But what about implementing this interface in C#?

Comment: Is it really an interface? Doesn't the ".class" mean it's a class? If it is an interface, that suggests the CLR allows member variables in interfaces. That's a new one on me. Very nice question.

Comment: Is it really an interface? because it has method implementation. Static methods not allowed in interface!!!

Comment: Your bascially trying to build an abstract Class here.

Comment: @Derek You can't inherit from multiple abstract classes, so it is (a bit) different

Comment: This is an interface, since `interface` keyword is used and its implementation is stored in `25(0x19) MethodImpl` metadata table.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis what i meant was, that hes looking for the functionality of an abstract class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# interface static method call with generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243921/c-sharp-interface-static-method-call-with-generics)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly (at least to me), your IL code compiles and verifies (use PEVerify for that) fine (assuming you add some `.assembly` directives).

And this is backed by the CLI specification (§I.8.9.4 Interface type definition):

> […] an interface type definition shall not provide field definitions for values of the interface type (i.e., instance fields), although it can declare static fields.
>
> […] An interface type definition can define and implement static methods since static
>   methods are associated with the interface type itself rather than with any value of the type.

But doing this is not CLS-compliant:

> CLS Rule 19: CLS-compliant interfaces shall not define static methods, nor shall they define fields.

And you can implement the interface in C#. The following code compiles and works fine:

```
class Test : ITest
{
    public void InstMethod(string s)
    { }
}
```

But it looks like you can't access the static field or the static method from C#.

Comment: It is indeed surprising. The CLR is a truly strange beast at times.

Comment: Indeed, I see no way to get the implemented static even via reflection: `var m = new Test().GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);`

Answer (score 1):

This is in reply to your comment that:

> I see no way to get the implemented static even via reflection: var m
>   = new Test().GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); –  user2341923

Remember, the declaring type of the method is an interface, so you must pull the method definition from the interface type. so roughly, I think this should work (using some linq extensions added)

```
var m = new Test().GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(
        i => i.IsAssignableFrom(
        typeof ITest)).First().GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

This would be true of any implemented members of an interface. Instance or otherwise.